# DOMPDF, collect filled input field

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm generating a PDF with the DOMPDF library, so far so good, but my collection of completed form fields is not being collected and shown in the PDF. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, I'll put part of my code below (I'm Brazilian, forgive me for my English)

HTML

```
<form class="form-req" id="form" method="POST">
   <div class="full-form">
      <h2><span>1</span> Data:</h2>
      <p>Benefit Plans</p>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-form">
      <div class="aside-form">
         <label for="completeName">Complete Name<b class="blue-obg">*</b></label>
         <input type="text" name="your-name" >
      </div>
      <div class="aside-form">
         <label for="cpf">CPF<b class="blue-obg">*</b></label>
         <input type="text" name="your-cpf" class="cpf" >
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="standard-button-form req-btn">
         <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Generate PDF">
    </div>

    <div class="alert">
        <span class="alert_error">Error</span>
        <span class="alert_sucess">PDF generated!</span>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form.form-req input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var formData = form.serialize(); 
            
            $.ajax({
              url: '../generate-pdf', //Through page in wordpress
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData, 
              success: function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  $('.alert_sucess').fadeIn();
                  window.location.replace("https://fabiocaspirro/generate-pdf");
              },
              error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  $('.alert_error').fadeIn();
              },
              complete: function () {
                  $('.alert_error, .alert_sucess').fadeOut(3000);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

generate-pdf.php

```
<?php

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);

$name = $_POST["your-name"];
$cpf = $_POST["your-cpf"];

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$content = '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <style>
                
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Define header and footer blocks before your content -->
            <header>

            </header>

            <footer>
            
            </footer>

            <!-- Wrap the content of your PDF inside a main tag -->
            <main>
            
                <table class="table table-dados-cadastrais">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <p class="title-field-form">Complete Name</p>
                                <span class="box-field-form">'.$name.'</span>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <p class="title-field-form">CPF</p>
                                <span class="box-field-form">'.$cpf.'</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </main>

        </body>
    </html>
';

$dompdf->loadHtml($content);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("Form", array("Attachment" => 1));
```

I don't know what else to do, I've tried different ways, but it's not working. It happens to generate the correct PDF, but it doesn't collect the variable that I fill in the form before sending

I hope to resolve this issue as soon as possible. I've been trying for 2 days to find the problem, I've tried several things without success. Among them, print_r, echo, **DIR**, files_get_contents, var_dump, trying to read data through another file with the html there... among others.

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems with your jQuery. Firstly, `$(this)` refers to your submit button, not your form. I suggest adding the event listener to the form submit. Secondly, use the full URL for the AJAX request. I've tested it locally on my machine, and it worked.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var formData = form.serialize(); 
            
            $.ajax({
              url: 'https://fabiocaspirro/generate-pdf.php', //Through page in wordpress
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData, 
              success: function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  $('.alert_sucess').fadeIn();
                  window.location.replace("https://fabiocaspirro/generate-pdf");
              },
              error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  $('.alert_error').fadeIn();
              },
              complete: function () {
                  $('.alert_error, .alert_sucess').fadeOut(3000);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Filip_Albert I was unable to generate the pdf correctly, when the pdf is generated the following error:

Error
Failed to load PDF document.

I would like to know what's not working. I did the same thing you mentioned.

Comment: @FabioCaspirro You mentioned in the code you access the WordPress page to generate the PDF. Did you create a theme's template file for the generator and set a new WordPress page in admin? Where exactly in your WordPress directory is the PHP script generating PDFs located? It works for me without using WordPress, but I could try it using within a WordPress environment.